# Finding the index of the minimum of each list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a list of the index's of the minimums of each list in a list of list. I have only been able to find an answer for a simple list.

```
data = [[9 ,5, 2, 8, 6], [3, 5, 1, 9, 2], [2, 9, 3, 0, 5]]
```

My first idea was to use

```
.index(min(n))
```

but it doesn't work for a list of lists.

Expected result:

```
new_list = [2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What if there's more than once instance of the minimum? Do you just want the index of the first?

Comment: Yes, I would index the first while creating a message to warn the user.

Comment: hang on... your expected result should be `[2, 2, 3]` - or do you really want to index from 1 instead of 0 ?

Comment: Are you sure that's your expected result? Those are 1-based indices, not 0-based.

Comment: Sorry yes it should be from 0.

Comment: @Cyphase now say I wanted the index of the minimum of each "column" to get [2, 0, 1, 2, 1] what would I have to change?

Comment: @Johnsmith, just do `zipped_data = zip(*data)`, then you can do it the same way that you do with `data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a list comprehension:

```
[x.index(min(x)) for x in data]
```

Comment: Now say I wanted the index of the minimum of each "column" to get [2, 0, 1, 2, 1] what would I have to change?

Comment: @Johnsmith `[x.index(min(x)) for xin list(zip(*data))]` but next time try a little hard

Answer (score 1):

```
     >>>data = [[9 ,5, 2, 8, 6], [3, 5, 1, 9, 2], [2, 9, 3, 0, 5]]
     >>>[x.index(min(x))+1 for x in data]

      [3, 3, 4] //actual index (Your required output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
result = []
for list in data:
    result.append(list.index(min(list)))
```

At the same time, the answer what you want to get is `[2,2,3]`, not `[3,3,4]`. Because the list's index start from `0`. I hope this can help you.